# Print the first, last, and in-between integers of a range

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-challenge, unit-testing

Given our [spec from Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175485/the-first-the-last-and-everything-between):

> Given two integers, output the two integers, and then the range between them.
>   The order of the range must be the same as the input.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> ```
>  Input        Output
>  0,  5   ->   [0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> -3,  8   ->   [-3, 8, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>  4,  4   ->   [4, 4]
>  4,  5   ->   [4, 5]
>  8,  2   ->   [8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
> -2, -7   ->   [-2, -7, -3, -4, -5, -6]
> ```

Using our test driven approach :)

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

public class CodeGolfTest {

@Test
public void firstLastAndEverythingBetweenExampleOTo5() {

    final List<Integer> integers = CodeGolf.firstLastAndEverythingBetween(0, 5);
    assertThat(integers).isNotNull().hasSize(6).containsExactly(0,5,1,2,3,4);


}

@Test
public void firstLastAndEverythingBetweenExampleMinus3To8() {

    final List<Integer> integers = CodeGolf.firstLastAndEverythingBetween(-3, 8);
    assertThat(integers).isNotNull().hasSize(12).containsExactly(-3,8,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);


}

@Test
public void firstLastAndEverythingBetweenExample4To4() {

    final List<Integer> integers = CodeGolf.firstLastAndEverythingBetween(4, 4);
    assertThat(integers).isNotNull().hasSize(2).containsExactly(4,4);


}

@Test
public void firstLastAndEverythingBetweenExample4To5() {

    final List<Integer> integers = CodeGolf.firstLastAndEverythingBetween(4, 5);
    assertThat(integers).isNotNull().hasSize(2).containsExactly(4,5);


}

@Test
public void firstLastAndEverythingBetweenExample8To2() {

    final List<Integer> integers = CodeGolf.firstLastAndEverythingBetween(8, 2);
    assertThat(integers).isNotNull().hasSize(7).containsExactly(8,2,7,6,5,4,3);


}

@Test
public void firstLastAndEverythingBetweenExampleMinus2ToMinus7() {

    final List<Integer> integers = CodeGolf.firstLastAndEverythingBetween(-2, -7);
    assertThat(integers).isNotNull().hasSize(6).containsExactly(-2,-7,-3,-4,-5,-6);


}
}
```

Can we optimize further this code?

The implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class CodeGolf {

    private CodeGolf() {
    }

    public static List<Integer> firstLastAndEverythingBetween(final int a, final int b) {

        if (a == b) {
            return addAB(a, b);
        }

        final List<Integer> result = addAB(a, b);
        int initial = getInitial(a, b);

        for (int n = 1; n < Math.abs(b - a); n++) {
            result.add(initial);
            if (b > a) {
                initial++;
            } else {
                initial--;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static int getInitial(int a, int b) {
        return (b > a) ? (a + 1) : (a - 1);
    }

    private static List<Integer> addAB(int a, int b) {
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(a);
        result.add(b);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your function:

```
public static List<Integer> firstLastAndEverythingBetween(final int a, final int b) {
    final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ a, b }));

    if (a == b) {
        return result;
    }

    int step = a > b ? -1 : 1;

    for (int i = a + step; i != b; i += step) {
        result.add(i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code Review is a site where we _review_ code. Providing an alternative implementation is fine, but you should at least explain _why_ it's better.

Comment: It looks ok, a detail, you don't need create an extra array of Integers, it is enough to do:  final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a, b));

Comment: I decided to set the answer as valid, but I would suggest for the next time to explain your contribution instead of "Here is your function". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for optimization:

- You re-evaluate `Math.abs()` in each iteration of the loop, which is a constant value. Consider `for(int n = 1, upperBound = Math.abs(b - a); n < upperBound; n++)` instead.
- The same goes for `if (b > a)` which is also constant. Maybe calculate an offset beforehand `int offset = (b > a) ? 1 : -1;` and then just add the offset in the loop.
- ... and if you already calculate such an offset, you may also use it to replace `getInitial()` with `initial = a + offset;`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what @mtj wrote:

`addAB` is a bad name. I'd call it something like `createInitalResult`. Also it's not necessary to call it twice. I'd have the start of the method as something like:

```
    final List<Integer> result = createInitalResult(a, b);

    if (a == b) {
        return result;
    }
```